# What is the correct assignment statement to update an integer in the following use of a dictionary? (Python 3.4.3)

Tags: python

```
d = {}
d['agency name'] = 0,{}
d['agency name'][1]['contractor 1'] = 0
d['agency name'][1]['contractor 2'] = 0
d['agency name'][1]['contractor 3'] = 0
print(d)

# the following line of code generates this error message:
# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
# why?
# what is the correct assignment statement to update an integer stored
# in the dictionary at d['agency name'][0]?

# error line
d['agency name'][0] = 1
# end error line

d['agency name'][1]['contractor 1'] = 1
print(d)
```

Comment: `d['agency name'] = 0,{}` assigns a tuple of `(0, {})` to that key. Tuples are immutable, hence the error message. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You could use a list. `d['agency name'] = [0, {}]`. Lists are mutable tuples

Comment: I'd recommend reconsidering your data structure, as nesting them so deeply can lead to confusion.

Comment: What format did you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of that tuples are [immutable objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) and you can not alter their elements(its value is unchangeable!).

```
>>> d['agency name']
(0, {'contractor 1': 1, 'contractor 3': 0, 'contractor 2': 0})
```

As you can see `d['agency name']` is a tuple so you can not change its values!

And if you want to change that values you can use a mutable object like list as a container :

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d['agency name'] = [0,{}]
>>> d['agency name'][1]['contractor 1'] = 0
>>> d['agency name'][1]['contractor 2'] = 0
>>> d['agency name'][1]['contractor 3'] = 0
>>> d['agency name'][0] = 1

>>> d
{'agency name': [1, {'contractor 1': 0, 'contractor 3': 0, 'contractor 2': 0}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant change values of a tuple after assigning. So create a temporary dictionary first for tuple item at index 1.

```
d = {}

temp_d = {
    'contractor 1': 0,
    'contractor 2': 0,
    'contractor 3': 0,
}

d['agency name'] = 0, temp_d
```

Comment: Using correct terminology from other answers and comments - Tuples are Immutable.

Answer (score 0):

In python, tuples are immutable, meaning you can't change the values inside a tuple. One way you can work around this is to create a new tuple with the values of the old tuple except for the ones you want to change.

```
d['agency name'] = (0,) + d['agency name'][1:]
```

The `[1:]` returns the same tuple excluding the first value. With this you can build a new tuple out of the tuple `(0,)`, and part of your old tuple `[1:]`. The effect is the same.

This is a slow work around compared to item assignment. If you are doing item assignment often, you should consider using lists instead which do support item assignment.